# pairwise datatable indices provided by two vectors in R

Tags: r, indexing, datatable

Assume we have a datatable DT with multiple rows and columns

```
DT <- data.table(c1=1:10, c2=11:20, C3=21:30)
```

and we have

```
a <- c(1,5,7)
b <- c(2,3,1)
```

Is there an easy way to generate a pair-wise combination of a and b and get the following items?

```
DT[1,2]
DT[5,3]
DT[7,1]
```

i.e., I expect to get

```
11, 25, 7
```

DT[a,b] returns a 3x3 datatable which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Need code for DT. Also nee you to specify what you expect since `[.data.table` does not behave like `[.data.frame`

Comment: Added a sample DT!

Comment: Outside of `data.table`, you can use matrix indexing, which is very quick - `as.data.frame(DT)[cbind(a,b)]`

Comment: DT[ cbind(a,b) ] worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Mahmoud - it shouldn't, as that code won't work on a `data.table`. But I think for this particular operation, a `data.table` is not very well suited.

Comment: It's actually going to be faster to not coerce and just use `[.data.frame`. I added another answer to the cited duplicate question which instead coerce to matrix (which would be even more dangerous.)